# Easiest and safest way to clean the startup disk

Tags: disk-utility, memory, performance, startup, disk-space

My 2018 MacBook Pro has plenty of storage and memory.

Recently it has grown remarkably slow, beyond frustratingly slow.

Not a day or even an hour goes by without any given application, software, website (or whatever) I'm using suddenly slows everything down, and then whatever I was using stops and crashes (typically causing at least 1 or 2 other actively  running programs to do the same)

I have at least 300-380ish GB of storage remaining on my internal hard-drive, enough in my iCloud, and I believe I have plenty of of Memory or RAM or whatever. I **believe** I have either 16 or 32 gigabytes of memory, I am not exactly an expert on the subject.

In summary, I hope to ask for help with generally how to best speed up my Mac, and, ideally and if possible also how best to maintain it to keep it running smoothly and fast.

Specifically I have 3 questions regarding that but that's my overall problem and question I have to ask for insight on.

Probably worth noting, I have recently downloaded many new apps and frankly don't even know what most do and definitely do not seem to know or how to determine what is running and when.

1. How do I delete and I fully uninstall a given app along with deleting all relating data/files etc? (To ensure nothing is left behind taking up space or possibly running)
2. How do I simply and efficiently learn/see which and what is currently running at any given time and then quit those which I'm not using and how do quit them in full and not allow them to automatically resume running unless I chose to open them?
3. Most important question: How do I safely, correctly & effectively clean up space on my startup disk?

(Any tips on how to correctly do anything mentioned and or generally how to fix whatever is causing my mac to run so slowly would all be deeply appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, you're not running low of disk space, so that's not the problem, and there's no immediate urgency to start deleting stuff. However, a tidy system is always a good thing.

You can use Activity Monitor (in `/Applications/Utilities`) to see what processes are running, and what is using excessive CPU and RAM.
You may need to click on **View > All Processes** to get a full picture.

(I usually leave it running all the time, so if something goes wrong, I can switch to it, rather than trying to load it when the system's slow.)

The Memory tab also has a nice little graph at the bottom, which shows you the memory pressure. Low and green is good; high and red is bad.

[image]

Note that it's normal for 'Memory Used" plus 'Cached Files' to equal the total size of your RAM.
If you can't see any particular process that's eating up memory or CPU, then we move to the next thing.

Look inside `/Library`, in two folders: `LaunchAgents` and `LaunchDaemons`. Note: this is the top level Library folder at the root level of your disk (next to System and Applications.) But also look in the same subfolders of your user account. (`~/Library`.)

This is where background processes that might run silently are stored. If you recognise the name of anything here, then see if that application has an uninstaller, or instructions for removal. *In extremis*, you can just delete it, and then restart.

You can also look at **Login Items** in **System Preferences > Users & Groups**.

You can see what apps you have installed in /Applications, of course. Most apps can just be deleted there, and they may leave behind a few configuration files, but these are usually tiny (Kilobytes) and will not do anything -- they won't be loaded in the absence of the app.

Anything that came with an installer package may need an uninstaller, and you should ask the developer for details.

I know you're trying to remove stuff, but you could use an app called [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com/en/index.html), which produces a report about the state of your Mac, including all third-party background processes, and other useful troubleshooting information. You can post the report here (there's no personal info in it), and someone may be able to identify any problems.